# Raphael Wheelnav piemenu creation - How to create multiple and minimized with just a plus symbol displayed

Tags: raphael, wheelnav.js

I'm trying to create 36 Rafael JS Navwheel Piemenu circular navigation menus on a game board screen, so that each game tile has a plus + symbol to click. 
I was able to achieve placing 2 menus on screen but they are fully maximized and displayed. I need them all to start out minimized/closed. 
If you click the 3rd example on this link: http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/examples.html and minimize it, I basically need all of my controls to start out like with the power off.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this??

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Thank you! 
-Ben

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id='piemenu' data-wheelnav
     data-wheelnav-slicepath='CogSlice'
     data-wheelnav-spreader data-wheelnav-spreaderpath='LineSpreader'
     data-wheelnav-marker data-wheelnav-markerpath='DropMarker'
     data-wheelnav-rotateoff
     data-wheelnav-navangle='330'
     data-wheelnav-cssmode
     data-wheelnav-init>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='0' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='1' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='2' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
</div>

<div id='piemenu2' data-wheelnav
     data-wheelnav-slicepath='CogSlice'
     data-wheelnav-spreader data-wheelnav-spreaderpath='LineSpreader'
     data-wheelnav-marker data-wheelnav-markerpath='DropMarker'
     data-wheelnav-rotateoff
     data-wheelnav-navangle='330'
     data-wheelnav-cssmode
     data-wheelnav-init>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='0' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='1' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
    <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='2' onmouseup='alert("Place your logic here.");'></div>
</div>


<script>
    window.onload = function () {

        var piemenu = new wheelnav('piemenu');
        piemenu.spreaderInTitle = icon.plus;
        piemenu.spreaderOutTitle = icon.cross;
        piemenu.spreaderRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.13;
        piemenu.clockwise = false;
        piemenu.sliceInitPathFunction = piemenu.slicePathFunction;
        piemenu.initPercent = 0.1;
        piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.83;
        piemenu.navItemsContinuous = true;
        piemenu.sliceAngle = 60;
        piemenu.createWheel();
        piemenu.setTooltips(['0','1','2']);

        var piemenu2 = new wheelnav('piemenu2');
        piemenu2.spreaderInTitle = icon.plus;
        piemenu2.spreaderOutTitle = icon.cross;
        piemenu2.spreaderRadius = piemenu2.wheelRadius * 0.13;
        piemenu2.clockwise = false;
        piemenu2.sliceInitPathFunction = piemenu2.slicePathFunction;
        piemenu2.initPercent = 0.1;
        piemenu2.wheelRadius = piemenu2.wheelRadius * 0.83;
        piemenu2.navItemsContinuous = true;
        piemenu2.sliceAngle = 60;
        piemenu2.createWheel();
        piemenu2.setTooltips(['0','1','2']);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael.icons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wheelnav.min.js"></script>


<style>
    /* Insert generated CSS code from here -> http://pmg.softwaretailoring.net */
    #piemenu > svg { width: 100%; height: 110%; }
    #piemenu { height: 115px; width: 180px; padding:0; margin:0; border:1px solid green; }
    @media (max-width: 180px) { #piemenu { height: 115px; width: 180px; } }

    #piemenu2 > svg { width: 100%; height: 110%; }
    #piemenu2 { height: 115px; width: 180px; padding:0; margin:0; border:1px solid green; }
    @media (max-width: 180px) { #piemenu2 { height: 115px; width: 180px; } }

    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover] { fill: #497F4C;  stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0.77; cursor: pointer; }

    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-slice-basic] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-slice-selected] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-slice-hover] { fill: #497F4C;  stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0.77; cursor: pointer; }

    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-basic] { fill: #333; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-selected] { fill: #fff; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-hover] { fill: #222; stroke: none; cursor: pointer; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title] > tspan { font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; }

    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-title-basic] { fill: #333; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-title-selected] { fill: #fff; stroke: none; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-title-hover] { fill: #222; stroke: none; cursor: pointer; }
    [class|=wheelnav-piemenu2-title] > tspan { font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; }

    .wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-in,
    .wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-out { fill: #444; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 2; cursor: pointer; }
    .wheelnav-piemenu-spreadertitle-in,
    .wheelnav-piemenu-spreadertitle-out { fill: #eee; stroke: #444; cursor: pointer; }

    .wheelnav-piemenu2-spreader-in,
    .wheelnav-piemenu2-spreader-out { fill: #444; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 2; cursor: pointer; }
    .wheelnav-piemenu2-spreadertitle-in,
    .wheelnav-piemenu2-spreadertitle-out { fill: #eee; stroke: #444; cursor: pointer; }

    .wheelnav-piemenu-marker { fill: #444; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 2; }
    .wheelnav-piemenu2-marker { fill: #444; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 2; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually finally just found this... its piemenu.spreadWheel(); 
This opens/closes your pie menus. I added this to the onload event: 
          piemenu.createWheel();
            piemenu.spreadWheel();
and it begins collapsed! Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: how about preventing the center spreader from collapsing / expanding at all?